# User objectIds are not displaying in RemoteDataTask

Tags: java, android, listview, parse-platform, android-asynctask

Here I have an AsyncTask that pulls data from my server and posts it to a list. Fairly simple stuff.

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SearchActivity.this);

            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading Results...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            // Create the array
            worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<SuggestedUser>();
            try {

                final ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                ob = query.find();
                Collections.shuffle(ob);

                for (ParseUser user : ob) {

                    ParseFile profilePicture = (ParseFile) user.get("profilePicture");
                    SuggestedUser map = new SuggestedUser();
                    map.setName((String) user.get("name"));
                    map.setUsername((String) user.get("username"));

                    if(profilePicture != null) {
                        map.setProfilePicture(profilePicture.getUrl());
                    }

                    map.setObjectId((String) user.get("objectId"));
                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_listview);

            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new SearchListViewAdapter(SearchActivity.this,
                    worldpopulationlist);

            // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

In my adapter, I run into the problem of the objectIds being spit out as null. What could possibly be going wrong here? Everything else works, including profilePicture, name, and username. Why aren't they being taken from the list?

```
//TODO Why aren't these being populated now?
holder.objectId = worldpopulationlist.get(position).getObjectId();
System.out.println(holder.objectId);
```

Here is my SuggestedUser class:

```
public class SuggestedUser {
    private String name;
    private String profilePicture;
    private String username;
    private String objectId;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getProfilePicture() {
        return profilePicture;
    }

    public void setProfilePicture(String profilePicture) {
        this.profilePicture = profilePicture;
    }

    public String getObjectId() { return objectId; }

    public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
        this.objectId = objectId;
    }
```

This is what I get in the console:

```
03-17 14:05:41.582 13238-13238/com.test.app I/System.out: null
03-17 14:05:41.589 13238-13238/com.test.app I/System.out: null
03-17 14:05:41.597 13238-13238/com.test.app I/System.out: null
03-17 14:05:41.604 13238-13238/com.test.app I/System.out: null
03-17 14:05:41.611 13238-13238/com.test.app I/System.out: null
03-17 14:05:41.617 13238-13238/com.test.app I/System.out: null
```

Comment: Try to put a log to find weather your getting data at  map.setObjectId((String) user.get("objectId"));

Comment: Thanks! I actually just tried that and it seems this is a special case where objectId can't be printed as a string without first saving the object it is referring to.

Comment: Did saving object helped to solve your problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a little research and found out that you can't retrieve a user objectId from a query without first saving it.

See my comments in the answer below. The solution is to modify the doInBackground() function as such:

```
for (ParseUser user : ob) {

                    // Save the object to make sure the objectId is generated!
                    user.save();

                    ParseFile profilePicture = (ParseFile) user.get("profilePicture");
                    SuggestedUser map = new SuggestedUser();
                    map.setName((String) user.get("name"));
                    map.setUsername((String) user.get("username"));

                    if(profilePicture != null) {
                        map.setProfilePicture(profilePicture.getUrl());
                    }

                    // Do not retrieve the objectId as a string, rather use the built-in Parse request, i.e. getObjectId();.
                    map.setObjectId((String) user.getObjectId());
                    worldpopulationlist.add(map);
                }
```